# setState is not updating state in callback

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state

I have the following callback associated to an onClick. This callback is supposed to remove the associated to do from the list based on id.

When I console.log, I can verify that the logic works, however when I use setState, it does not work.

I have also tried via a callback function... I can confirm that the callback function is being called, it is specifically the setState function not working.

Why?

```
state = {
    todos: [],
    todoToShow: 'all',
  };

CALLBACK:

 handleDeleteTodo = (id) => {
    this.setState((state) => {
      return {
        todos: this.state.todos.filter((todo) => todo.id !== id) ,
      };
    });
  };
```

The way todos are being rendered:

````
    if (this.state.todoToShow === 'all') {
      todos = this.state.todos;
    } else if (this.state.todoToShow === 'active') {
      todos = this.state.todos.filter((todo) => !todo.complete);
    } else if (this.state.todoToShow === 'complete') {
      todos = this.state.todos.filter((todo) => todo.complete);
    }

{todos &&
          todos.map((todo) => (
            <Todo
              todo={todo}
              key={todo.id}
              // id={todo.id}
              toggleComplete={() => this.toggleComplete(todo.id)}
              // text={todo.text}
              onDelete={() => this.handleDeleteTodo(todo.id)}
            />
          ))}```
````

Comment: What's your `Todo` component look like?

Comment: To be honest, this looks like it should work, I would try to analyse further what could be going wrong, like perhaps your doing !== with a string and a number. What I would do is split this into a few lines and debug to see whats happening. Transform the state into what you want in one step and set that as a variable, then set that variable in the next step so you can step through and see whats going on. (I.E. the line     this.setState((state) => {
      return {
        todos: this.state.todos.filter((todo) => todo.id !== id) ,
      };
    });
 `

Comment: Other than ***not*** using the previous state when deleting a TODO, (i.e. `this.setState(state => ({ todos: state.todos.filter((todo) => todo.id !== id) }));`) I agree, it appears to be syntactically correct. ***How*** are you checking that state is or isn't updating? Perhaps it is a type comparison issue. Have you written any unit tests against the function/component? Can you provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) code example, i.e. the entire component code?